# Faulty Verbatim Powerbay data bank

Tags: data-recovery, raid

The system is Verbatim PowerBay data bank, with 4 hard disks configured as RAID 5. The problem started when one of the hard disks light flashed. Then we couldn't get any data from the NAS. How I can fix it or just retrieve data from the hard disks. I disassembled the hard disks, linked them to my laptop and checked them (testdisk) each in a separate terminal. I checked using quick check and deep check (toke more than a day and a half). But nothing recovered. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to recover the RAID5 setup within the NAS, using the tools available there. You can't expect to recover files from the nas-disks looking at them one by one in Ubuntu, since data is spread across all four disks. And you probably can't rebuild  the raid setup under Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the data is spread allover the hard disks, that is why I connected all the four disks to my laptop. I checked the master one /dev/md0 using mdadm --detail /dev/md0 and it gave me the info mentioning in the bottom the drives as [U___] does this help?